# Passing JQuery .post variable dynamically to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a JQuery variable into PHP code within a single page. It appears that the JQuery variable is firing (I get the confirmation alert back), but it is not being read by the PHP. How do I fix this? *edited for clarity

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("div").click(function(){
                        var pastDATE = $(this).text();
                        $.post("testclick.php", 'pastDATE', function() {
                            alert(pastDATE, "post success");
                        });
                    });
                });
                /*
                var pastDATE = (div.calendar-head
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "testclick.php",
                    data: {pastDATE: pastDATE},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                */      
        </script>
    <style>

    .calendar-head {
        display: block;
        line-height: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #2F4F4F;
        color:  #2F4F4F;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        }

    </style>    
<body>

<div class="calendar-head">This</div>

<?php

/*attempted to start a session so when page is refreshed the variable remains*/

session_start();
    $_SESSION['pastDATE'] = $pastDATE;

$pastDATE = $_POST['pastDATE'];

if(isset($_POST['pastDATE'])){
    $pastDATE = $_POST['pastDATE'];
    echo "set";
    }

echo "$pastDATE";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're sending the name of a post variable with no value. It should be something like `pastDATE=2009-03-01`.

Comment: `{ pastDate: '2009-03-01' }`

Comment: The post variable should be the data that is clicked. In other words, pastDATE = This would be the variable I am trying to send. Does that make sense?

Comment: Move your `session_start();` to the top of your file. Session starts only, if there was no output before. A simple line break or a space is output, so start the session before any output!

Comment: And what do you do in your PHP? `$_SESSION['pastDATE'] = $pastDATE;` is useless, because $pasteDATE has no value. Why do you create that variable?

Comment: pastDATE becomes a variable when I click the div, I need to know how to pass that variable dynamically to the php via a page refresh or other means.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("testclick.php", { pastDATE: pastDATE }, function() {
    alert(pastDATE, "post success");
});
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Change JavaScript code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var pastDATE = $(this).text();
        $.post("testclick.php", { data:pastDATE }, function(result) {
            alert(pastDATE, "post success");
        });
    });
});
```

And read on PHP like `$_REQUEST['data']`

Comment: The JQuery is working perfectly as far as I can tell. However, 'data' is still being read as NULL within the PHP after I click and refresh the page.

Comment: I don't know what you want about $pastDATE?

$_SESSION['pastDATE'] = $pastDATE; is not work because $pastDATE undefined before.